# How to get date from dijit.form.DateTextBox in given format?

Tags: date, dojo

I have a dojo text box  in a html file.Now i want to  retrieve the date from text box in a string format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. How can i do it?

```javascript
  dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a reference `widget` to your DateTextBox widget using something like `dijit.byId(...)` or `dijit.byNode(dojo.query(...))`, this will get the Javascript Date object and format it according to ISO 8601 standard (yyyy-mm-dd), independent of the display or the locale you happen to be using

```javascript
 dojo.require('dojo.date.stamp');
 ...
 var dateObject = widget.get('value');
 var isoFormat = dojo.date.stamp.toISOString(dateObject, {selector: 'date'});
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:
HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="2005-12-30"
   dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" required="true" />
```

To get displayed value you can use this method of date text box:

```javascript
// get widget:
    var dtb = dijit.byId('date1');
// get value
    alert(dtb.get('displayedValue'));
```

**NOTE***:

Dojo format the date according user locale.

IF you can use format which differs with user locale format you need specify constraint property for date text box.

```html
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="2005-12-30" 
  constraints="{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd', strict:true}" 
  dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" required="true" />
```

[HTML Page - example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1e1oiso.html)

Comment: you don't have to change the visual display to yyyy-mm-dd in order to achieve this.  Dojo keeps the Date attribute independent of the displayedValue

Comment: @peller: yes, i know it. However, if I understand correctly, the goal was to get value from textbox in the right format (for example, to send to the server) and not change the display format. I also think it's bad practice to manually change the date format. Date to be displayed depending on the user's culture.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you can just use the widget's [`toString` method](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001819/ch13.html#additionally_m).

```
var isoString = dijit.byId(widgetId).toString();
```